# How to determine if a given tweet is a video?

Tags: twitter-search

Let’s say I have two tweets:

1. https://twitter.com/BuzzFeed/status/917922958307295233
2. https://twitter.com/BuzzFeed/status/876083996026916865

I want to be able to quickly determine if the tweet contains a video. What is the best way to do that?

I’ve tried using oEmbed API, but it doesn’t give me the information I need.
https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines/oembed

Answer (score 0):

Posting a temporary answer
I have an access to the embedded html of the tweet. Thus, the first tweet example will have the embedded html of:

```
<blockquote class=\"twitter-tweet\" data-lang=\"en\"><a href=\"https://twitter.com/BuzzFeed/status/917922958307295233?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw\" /></blockquote>
```

and second tweet example will have the embedded html of:

```
<blockquote class=\"twitter-video\" data-lang=\"en\"><a href=\"https://twitter.com/BuzzFeed/status/876083996026916865?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw\" /></blockquote>
```

I can simply look at the blockquote class name to determine if the twitter is a video or a simple tweet.

This solution, however, will not work if you do not have access to the embedded html of the tweet, thus leaving this question still open for answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter:videos` advanced search operator in Twitter search to filter out only tweets containing videos like `from:BuzzFeed filter:videos` [for example](https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&q=from%3ABuzzFeed%20filter%3Avideos). Such filter can be coupled with other filters and/or Boolean arguments to make sure you narrow the search to only the tweets you wish to verify.